# Import Leaflet Dragend Event to pyqtlet

Tags: javascript, python, leaflet, pyqt5

In Pyqtlet, I can link map events to the Pyqt signal-slot structure via the following codes.

map.py:

```
clicked = pyqtSignal(dict)

@pyqtSlot(QJsonValue)
    def _onClick(self, event):
        self._logger.debug('map clicked. event: {event}'.format(event=event))
        self.clicked.emit(self._qJsonValueToDict(event))

self._connectEventToSignal('click', '_onClick')
```

evented.py

```
def _connectEventToSignal(self, event, signalEmitter):
    print(self.jsName + "\n")
    print(event + "\n")
    print(signalEmitter + "\n")

    # We need to delete some keys as they are causing circular structures
    js = '{name}.on("{event}", function(e) {{\
              delete e.target;\
              delete e.sourceTarget;\
              e = copyWithoutCircularReferences([e], e);\
              channelObjects.{name}Object.{signalEmitter}(e)}})'.format(
        name=self.jsName, event=event, signalEmitter=signalEmitter)
    self.runJavaScript(js)
```

But the same code doesn't work for add marker drag event in maker.py. The error I get is: "js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_onDrag' of undefined". I think there is an error in my javascript code. How can I solve it?